# Spring boot web service dependency issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services

I am developing spring boot soap client.I was initialized the project using https://start.spring.io/
spring version 2.2.2.RELEASE. pom.xml shows error indicate failed to read to spring-boot-starter-web.jar  2.2.2.RELEASE. Following is my pom.xml using ide -intelj idea 14

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.websevice</groupId>
    <artifactId>arogya</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>arogya</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to be an issue with your IDE, and you didn't mention which IDE you're using. You likely need to refresh the project dependencies in the IDE. How to do that depends on the IDE.

Comment: I think it's Intellij. Use option : Clear and invalidate cache

Comment: Issue with the ide. latest version works properly

Comment: Try this:
Navigate to 'Project Structure', select 'Modules' pane -> 'Dependencies' tab and remove duplications. And the same action in 'Libraries' pane.
Then, right-click on pom-file -> maven -> reimport.